# Cloudy information popup box

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to create a little information box. So when you hover over the image with your mouse you see a little box in the shape of a cloud and you can read some info in it.
I've seen this on loads of websites. I tried searching the whole web, but only found javascript popup boxes. But thoose only popup in a whole new screen.

Help is appriciated! :)

Cheers, 
Jesse

code:

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username"><p>
<input type="text" name="password" id="password">
<img src="files.directofficesupport.com/img/randompassgen_16x16.png" alt="Random password generator">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try by using the :hover pseudo-element (CSS) and creating a semi-transparent background for the container in order to represent the cloud.

If you provide some HTML code, I can try to help you updating this answer with CSS.

In the meanwhile, you can find a simple, yet beautiful, example in here:
http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/11/how-to-create-a-simple-css3-tooltip/

Comment: IMG is not a valid tag for this purpose. I'll update the answer in order to show what I mean.

Comment: check the link. I believe it will help you!

Comment: Thank you very much Opalenzuela!